# Is Serbian u from "buva" flea a Proto-Slavic ъ or l from *blъxa?

Tags: bosnian-croatian-serbian

Is Serbian u from "buva" flea a Proto-Slavic ъ or l from *blъxa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely both. In Slavic languages, sounds corresponding to Proto-Slavic lъ/ъl often [go together as a unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_liquid_metathesis_and_pleophony) and can change places in different forms of the same word. So do lь/ьl, rъ/ъr, rь/ьr.

Serbo-Croatian's ["dark" pronunciation of l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbo-Croatian_phonology#cite_ref-9) makes the lъ/ъl combination sound very much like "u". There's a pattern in the spelling of words like [vuna](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vuna#Serbo-Croatian) (wool), [puno](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puno#Serbo-Croatian) (a lot), [Bugarska](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bugarska#Serbo-Croatian) (Bulgaria), [gutati](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gutati#Serbo-Croatian) (swallow), etc where the corresponding Proto-Slavic forms had lъ/ъl/lь/ьl.